# Merging migrated makes much mayhem

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, migrated-questions, merged-questions

To reproduce:

1. Migrate a question (with votes) to a site
2. On the site that received the question, try merging the question with an existing one, choosing to remove the migrated question.
3. You will get an error message.

For more information (and some comments by @waffles that might help), see this chat: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/223820#223820

<sub>Credit for the awesome title goes to @random</sub>

Comment: That is... the most amazing 404 page I've ever seen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great find - this has been fixed on development and will be pushed out tonight.

Comment: That was pretty quick, thanks for the fix!

Comment: @Senseful that's what I'm here for :)